# Linphonec on RaspberryPi: how to solve "bctbx-error-bctbx_file_open (Permission denied)"

Tags: raspberry-pi, linphone

In my setting I want the user www-data to be able to run linphonec, but there's one error in my way, that I don't know how to handle so far.

When starting linphonec as user www-data:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/linphonec
```

I get the error:

```
bctbx-error-bctbx_file_open: Error open Permission denied
```

Where do I have to give permission to user www-data for this to work?
When running it as root there's no problem but I don't want to give www-data root rights.

**My setting is:**

- RaspberryPi 3/4,
- with newest Raspian OS,
- newest version of "linphonec-cli" installed
- raspbi is only accessible in local network and router blocks outgoing calls from it to prevent missuse.

Comment: Not sure about this particular problem but a general solution can be: Check using [strace](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=5ae64bfc-1fa3-4c3f-b125-d0b059ad893f) (you can use `-e status=failed -e trace=file`) which file exactly is accessed here, then set the group of the file to www-data.

Comment: thank you @CherryDT , I didn't know about strace. The output doesn't contain anything about 'bctbx' but it gives me several directories I will check for permissions.

Comment: Look for those with result `EACCES`, that means permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

After checking with *`strace`* I realized thet the issue must be somewhere else, since I couldn't find a single `EACCES` error in the strace log.

The root of the error was in my basic configurations file (`linphonerc`) that I copied over from another existing user. I changed the *`root_ca`* directory (after copying the files to the new location and changing rw-rights and ownership). After that linphonec runs without the error when starting with `-c` parameter and path to linphonerc file.

So the reason was most likely that wrong/unreachable root_ca= configuration.